Module Federation between Nx Monorepo Reactjs and Normal Reactjs (CRA)
I'm researching how to expose a component in an NX React app (the remote) so it can be consumed by a standard React app (the host) which is not part of the NX module. I've read the NX documentation and searched the internet for days, but I haven't found a helpful answer yet; most of the examples were focused on NX to NX. I also tried to configure some samples, and while it works between standard React apps, I'm encountering errors when trying to connect an NX app with a standard React app. If anyone has an example, could you please provide it to me?
Thanks!
